# How manage Rails log/development.log with Git(Hub) and multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, merge, centos

I am newish to Rails and GitHub and struggling with managing two coders' development logs. Specifically:

1. How do I merge two developers development logs?
2. Can I automate their merger? Or can I differentiate them in some Railsy or GitHub Flowy way?

The Rails app I am developing on command line CentOS 6 is being worked on by another developer. We are using a private GitHub repo to help us manage our codebase and are trying to follow [The GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html).

This strategy works well for almost every aspect of our project. The only major problem I've run into with this so far is that our development logs are (of course) out of sync. For instance, he branches from master, then I do. Then he merges to master, then I do, but my merge will fail, citing the automatic merge failure on log/develoment.log. Our logs will be structured like this:

*log/development.log - mine*  
Shared: (Tens of thousands of lines of code from master branch point) 
Not:    (Thousands of lines of code unique to my branch)

*log/development.log - his* 
Shared: (Tens of thousands of lines of code from master branch point) 
Not:    (Thousands of lines of code unique to his branch)

So, I find going through this manually, even with diff tools like `git mergetool`, impractical because of the volumes of code involved. (Am I simply too much of a vim novice to be able to put this to good use? Do others find this trivial?)

1. Is there a git or rails development strategy we can employ to keep these files without them clashing? (ex: some tinkering with Rails configuration to designate 'Development1' environment vs. 'Development2' environment)?
2. Is there some command line tool that merges two clashing logs based on time last updated? I'm imaging a tool that, given two clashing git-tracked documents can merge them by comparing the branch point/time, using that as the 'shared' base and adding in the remainder based on which was more recently updated (more recent > appended last). A more advanced version would walk back through commit history to append updates based on commit timestamps.

Comment: should belong to your gitignore...

Comment: seek inspiration here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

Comment: OK, so I'll take it as the standard that this should be part of the `.gitignore`. (Honestly, I should have thought of this: I never reference it...) And thanks for the link. Can you answer: What is the primary purpose of the development log? I guess I assumed it was meant to be a communal dev data change log ...  Also, if you want to answer this (instead of commenting) I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs are useful for your own purposes:

- check requests sent
- check params sent
- check correct matching url/controller-action
- check sql queries
- check your own stuff (you can log things if you desire)

So because its for your only purpose, no need to pollute your repository with it: add log folder to your gitignore.

[There is a recommended gitignore for Rails projects here.](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore)

BTW, if logs in console are enough for you, save your disk space and add:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

in `development.rb`